# Something wrong with Inner Join on Teradata

Tags: mysql, teradata-sql-assistant

I had to find a particular number on consumers on a network. Client suggested to use `table "abcd"` and to make sure that `manufacturer='big_company"` is met. So I ran below query on Teradata.

```
select count(*)from(select tel_num, manufacturer from abcd
where manufacturer='big_company'
and tel_num is not null)pqr
```

This query ran properly and the total number of record were 600 million.

The another question client had was, Out of the consumers on network how many of them are choosing a particular service. I was being asked to use table "wxyz" and ensure postpaid=1 condition is met. To achieve this I had to create inner join between abcd and wxyz on tel_num. Below was the query I used:

```
select cast (count (*)as bigint) from (select a.tel_num, b.postpaid from 
abcd as a inner join wxyz as b on a.tel_num=b.tel_num
where a.manufacturer='big_company'
and b.postpaid=1) xyz
```

The above query generates 5 billion records.

This seems very strange because, since I have used inner join the number of records in the second query should be less than 600 million. I'm just not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: it may be giving you duplicate record using join.. check using `DISTINCT` something like this    `COUNT ( DISTINCT a.tel_num)`

Comment: I wonder how can I get duplicate values when I'm using inner join.

Comment: Thanks. Using Distinct resolved the issue. Thanks a pile  I wonder how I forgot such a basic rule to use Distinct. Felt like a bummer 

Answer (score 1):

As @useless'MJ already put it in a comment, you are probably getting multiple results per `tel_num` from table `wxyz`. You could avoid `JOIN`and `distinct` altogether by using `EXISTS` like in

```
select cast (count (*)as bigint) 
from abcd a
where exists (select 1 from wxyz b
  where a.tel_num=b.tel_num and b.postpaid=1)
and a.manufacturer='big_company'
```

Comment: I wonder how can I get duplicate values when I'm using inner join.

Comment: Your comment helped me to understand why I could have got multiple results per tel_num. Thank you 